# Using File Projection in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am using QGIS AND struggling with setting projections. I am attempting to reproject all of my files that I am accumulating into NAD83-UTMzone13 utilizing the reprojection tool.  The tool appears to run correctly, I save the file. I set the project projection under the properties. When I add the shape, 1. the project reverts back to WGS84 and 2. the newly projected shape still does not show up, even when I reset the project back to the desired projection.
Thoughts?

Comment: Instead of the reprojection tool, try exporting the layer (right click on the layer name > export), and change the CRS of the export.

Comment: What happens when you zoom to the layer (right click on the layer name > zoom to layer)? Is the layer present, but in the wrong location? Or is it not there at all?

Comment: Make sure the data you're trying to re-project is actually inside UTM zone 13.